# Unit Test for Apex Trigger that Concatenates Fields

Tags: unit-testing, triggers, salesforce, apex

I am trying to write a test for a before trigger that takes fields from a custom object and concatenates them into a custom Key__c field.

The trigger works in the Sandbox and now I am trying to get it into production. However, whenever I try and do a System.assert/assertEquals after I create a purchase and perform DML, the value of Key__c always returns null. I am aware I can create a flow/process to do this, but I am trying to solve this with code for my own edification. How can I get the fields to concatenate and return properly in the test? (the commented out asserts are what I have tried so far, and have failed when run)

```
trigger Composite_Key on Purchases__c (before insert, before update) {
if(Trigger.isBefore)
{
    for(Purchases__c purchase : trigger.new)
    {
        String eventName = String.isBlank(purchase.Event_name__c)?'':purchase.Event_name__c+'-';
        String section = String.isBlank(purchase.section__c)?'':purchase.section__c+'-';
        String row = String.isBlank(purchase.row__c)?'':purchase.row__c+'-';
        String seat = String.isBlank(String.valueOf(purchase.seat__c))?'':String.valueOf(purchase.seat__c)+'-';
        String numseats = String.isBlank(String.valueOf(purchase.number_of_seats__c))?'':String.valueOf(purchase.number_of_seats__c)+'-';
        String adddatetime = String.isBlank(String.valueOf(purchase.add_datetime__c))?'':String.valueOf(purchase.add_datetime__c);
        purchase.Key__c = eventName + section + row + seat + numseats + adddatetime;
    }
}
```

}

```
@isTest
public class CompositeKeyTest {
public static testMethod void testPurchase() {
    //create a purchase to fire the trigger
    Purchases__c purchase = new Purchases__c(Event_name__c = 'test', section__c='test',row__c='test', seat__c=1.0,number_of_seats__c='test',add_datetime__c='test');

    Insert purchase;

    //System.assert(purchases__c.Key__c.getDescribe().getName() == 'testesttest1testtest');
    //System.assertEquals('testtesttest1.0testtest',purchase.Key__c);       
}
static testMethod void testbulkPurchase(){
    List<Purchases__c> purchaseList = new List<Purchases__c>();
    for(integer i=0 ; i < 10; i++)
    {
         Purchases__c purchaserec = new Purchases__c(Event_name__c = 'test', section__c='test',row__c='test', seat__c= i+1.0 ,number_of_seats__c='test',add_datetime__c='test');
        purchaseList.add(purchaserec);
    }
    insert purchaseList;
   //System.assertEquals('testtesttest5testtest',purchaseList[4].Key__c,'Key is not Valid');
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to requery the records after inserting them to get the updated data from the triggers/database